# AWS CLI to restrict inbound connections from a dynamic IP

Tags: security, amazon-web-services, ip, command-line-interface

My internet provider doesn't offer static IP, so I have to connect to my AWS instances with a  dynamic IP. That means that my VPC security group in AWS has a ssh port that can be accessed from every IP (source: 0.0.0.0/0), obviously if you have the key.

I would want to restrict this rule, and I was thinking of writing a CLI script that revokes this 0.0.0.0 rule and creates a new inbound rule with my (dynamic) IP.

Is it possible? Is it a good idea?

Comment: I made an [npm module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/aws-ip) to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You could connect through a VPN.  Then SSH from inside the VPN.

setup a software VPN (OpenVPN, OpenSwan) on an existing instance and open just that port to the outside world.  Once setup it would essentially be free if you are running it on an instance that you would normally run.  This will have a little more setup involved but it's not too hard.

> *Previously I suggested the Amazon VPC VPN.  But that requires a static IP so that will not work*

Comment: But then I have to assign the 0.0.0.0 rule to the VPN, haven't I? What is the advantage then?

Comment: You wouldn't be opening SSH to the world just the VPN ports of UDP 500,4500.  Either way you have to open something to be able to get inside.  Also with using a VPN you would have another layer of security.  Someone would need your VPN credentials AND your ssh credentials to connect to your instance.

Comment: @greg_diesel the VPC VPN service requires a static IP at the customer side.

Comment: Thanks @Michael-sqlbot.  Edited the above answer to remove the Amazon VPC VPN since it required static